# Gotchas: Upgrading from single servers to web farms

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2003, web-farm

Our company currently runs two Windows 2003 servers (a web server & a MSSQL 8 database server). We're planning to add another couple of servers for redundancy / availability purposes in a web farm setup. Our web sites are predominately ASP.NET, we do have a few PHP sites, but these are mainly static with no DB.

Does anyone who has been through this process have any gotchas or other points I should be aware of? And would using Windows Server 2008 offer any additional advantages for this situation (so I can convince my boss to upgrade :) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have dynamic load balancing (i.e. My first request goes to server X, but my next Request may go to server Y or Z), you will find out that In-Proc Sessions do not work. So you will either need sticky Sessions (your load balancer will ALWAYS send me (=my session) to server X) or out-of-process sessions (i.e. stored in an SQL Server).

Answer (score 4):

Like Michael says, you'll need to take care of your session.  Ideally make it lean and store out of process.  You'll have similar challenge with cache depending on how you use it and might be interested in looking towards a more robust caching technology if you only use asp caching.

Don't forget things like machine keys and validation in your web.config.  The machineKeys need to be consistant across your servers.

Read up on IIS7 and you should be able to pick out several good examples to show off to your boss.

A web farm can give you opportunities and challenges with deployment that should not be overlooked.

Without specifc experience to the setup above but to general moves of this kind.  I would recommend phasing the approach.  That is, move to Windows 2008 first and then farm.

Comment: +1 for machineKeys. That is a reliable source for hard to debug and very subtle bugs when they are not equal.

Answer (score 4):

One additional thing to look at is your deployment plan.  Deployment plans seem to be sadly overlooked and/or undervalued.  Remember that you are deploying to multiple nodes and you want to take into account how you want to deploy and test in a logical fashion.

For example, assume you have four nodes in your farm.  Do you pull two out of the cluster and update and test, then swapping out the other two to repeat?  Determine if your current deployment process fits in with the answer you provide.  Just because you have X times the amount of servers does not mean that you want or need to do X times the amount of work.

Just revisiting the caching part of the conversation for a moment.  You should definitely take a look at a distributed caching solution.  If you are pre-caching data and using callbacks with cache removals, you can really put a pounding on the database if you are not careful.  Also, a lot of the distributed caching solutions offer some level of session state management, as well.  I have been very much enjoying Microsoft's Velocity project, although it is just a second CTP release and not ready for production.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, you might want to consider looking into Richard Campbell's (of .NET Rocks!) product:

http://www.strangeloopnetworks.com/

Comment: We have evaluated the appliance and have been quite impressed.  Not only does Richard have a site application appliance, there is a web service appliance.  Probably with the next budget review, we are going to move forward with at least one of their offerings.

Answer (score 1):

We use the ASP.NET State Server for handling out sessions. This comes free with windows server 2003/2008.

We then have to make sure the machine key's are the same (a setting in your web.config files).

I then manually take each site offline (using app.offline or whatever the magic file is called). Alternatively, u can use IIS and just turn the site off and the offline site 'on'.

That's about it. You could worry about distributed caching, but that's pretty hard-core stuff. You can get a lot of good millage out of the default Output Caching with ASP.NET. I'd start there, before you delve into the complexity (and cost, for some products) if you're going to do distributed caching.

Oh, we're using an F5 load balancer that does NOT do sticky sessions, so we need to maintain our sessions .. which is why we're using the ASP.NET state server.

Answer (score 1):

One other gotcha aside from the Session issues described by the other posters is if the apps are writing to the local file system. Scaling out to a web farm would break the apps if they assume the files are on the local PC. For example, uploaded files might be available or not depending on which server is hit. Changing the paths to point to a shared drive should fix this.